# Simple search based on MySQL

Tags: mysql

For each item I have two fields (these values): name (for example, iPhone) and manufacturer (for example, Apple) - and I want to implement search by these fields.

Should I use MySQL built-in search mechanisms or something like Sphinx? Any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: What's the purpose of this search? Are you just trying to view the data or do you have a scripting language you're working with?

Comment: The purpose is to give relevant results according to search query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your table size. I would start using pure MySQL queries and indexing tables where applicable. Once your queries take too much time, even with indexed tables, I would consider search servers like Sphinx.